# logstash output error in sending logs to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I read my services logs using filebeat ,then filebeat sends the logs to logstash for parsing. logstash sends the parsed logs to elasticsearch to be indexed.
But today this error happens in logstash and no logs is indexed in elasticsearch.

> [2021-11-02T11:35:36,774][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could
> not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index",
> {:_id=>nil, :_inde ::Event:0xf85da17>],
> :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-alias-000015",
> "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"YNas33wBlcfHwocoMbSU", "status"=>400,
> "error"=>{"type" ls.Usage.UserUsage] of type [float] in document with
> id 'YNas33wBlcfHwocoMbSU'. Preview of field's value: 'NaN'",
> "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exc ]"}}}}}

I searched but did not find a clue, Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you get, a field called `ls.Usage.UserUsage` of type float contains the value `'NaN'` which is not a float.

What you could do is to modify your mapping to set the [`ignore_malformed` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) to true so that this value is ignored, but it won't prevent the document from being indexed.

The other option is to make sure to not produce such wrong values upstream.